# New Digest email going out with no-reply@sharepointonline.com address as supposed to real address

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-news

A user account is being tested to send out new digest to the entire company via distribution list. that distribution list is restricted to specific accounts including the aforementioned user account. Not done by me but the initial tests were successful and sent out to all employees correct. Subsequent tests are going out with the sender as no-reply@sharepointonline.com but using the display name of user account. no-reply@sharepointonline.com is not authorized to use the internal DL of course so the email never reaches its recipients.

News digest sent from other accounts to only a *couple of recipients* work just fine. Testing emails to the entire organization is not something done lightly.

Why are news digest emails going out with a generic address as supposed the address of the account "sending" the email in Sharepoint?

Comment: After talking with Microsoft support this appears to be a known bug with no ETA specified. I cannot find anything official to link to just emails from technical leads and supervisors.